# Patent filling in Argentina

Tags: patent-applications, filling, argentina

Argentina is not part of the PCT and needs filling via national route. Does anyone know what are the basic steps and cost for filling there with a priority document written in English?

I imagine that a translation and a local attorney are necessary.

If available share a link for online filing

Comment: I also have this question. Did you ever figure it out @chempatent1981?

Comment: We ended up naturally with a local patent attorney, who took care of the translation. The unusual part was that it required a lot of signatures, verifications and authorizations. I think our formalities officer even had to go to the Argentinian embassy for some papers. Cost without translation was around 1500 US$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have filed an application in other country，you should file application in Argentina in 12 months.

You firstly need to translate the application into Spanish.
Then, entrust a IP law firm in Argentina to handle the case.

I am a patent attorney in China, I handled cases for our client into Argentina. If you need I can recommend an attorney to you.